# EditText cursor bug after dialog close

Tags: android, android-edittext

[image: bug demo]

I'm facing a problem. Not sure what to call it, or what causes it

I'm learning Android SQLite and to train started making a simple note app.

The problem is I have a custom dialog for category select, before opening the dialog everything is fine in the EditText field, but after opening, and closing it the text starts writing over, like creating multiple layers of the same text and the text cursor leaves a line after every symbol. (See "bug demo" GIF of the problem)

Has anyone else seen something like this? What could be causing this, the dialog?

Edit:

So this is the code that takes action when clicking on the star to open the dialog

```
 starred.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CreateNoteActivity.this);
                View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_category_select, null);
                ListView categoryList = mView.findViewById(R.id.category_list);
                Button cancelSelect = mView.findViewById(R.id.cancelSelect);

                final CategoryListAdapter adapter = new CategoryListAdapter(CreateNoteActivity.this);
                categoryList.setAdapter(adapter);
                //get the data and append to a list
                Cursor data = myDB.getCategories();
                while(data.moveToNext()){
                    Category thisNote = new Category(data.getInt(0), data.getString(1), data.getString(2));
                    adapter.add(thisNote);
                }

                categoryList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int i, long l) {
                        final Category selectedCategory = (Category) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                        String s = "Category celected: "+selectedCategory.getCategoryName();
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, s, duration);
                        toast.show();
                    }
                });

                builder.setView(mView);

                final AlertDialog selectCategory = builder.create();
                selectCategory.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
                selectCategory.show();
                View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
                decorView.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
                int width = (int)(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels*0.80);
                int height = (int)(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels*0.80);

                selectCategory.getWindow().setLayout(width, height);

                cancelSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        selectCategory.dismiss();
                    }
                });

        }
    });
```

Comment: Cool bug :) Post some relevant code so we can try to help..

Comment: What version of Android? Are there any versions that aren't affected?

Comment: My phone is API 24, emulator had API 25

Comment: Can you provide the edit text logic, it seems the issue is related to "how you are going to play with the edit text "

Comment: Not much logic to provide, there is just a simple multiLine EditText field from witch I take the content and save in into the database, but it seems that I found what was causing the problem, not sure why though.

Answer (score 2):

This answer might help you

Write this after the dialog close

```
ediText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length);
```

Basically using the above logic, the cursor won't be pointed at the first character of the `editText` on the `dialog` close

Answer (score 1):

Noticed that I was trying to set a transparent background to display my custom dialog bcg two times.
So what fixed the problem was removing two lines

```
*View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
decorView.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);*
```

Not sure why it was causing this. Should check what is getDecorView() method. Used it cause found it as a solution to show the custom background.

This line works as well

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
```

Guess this was a case of *rubber duck debugging* - just had to tell someone about the problem to fix it. Thanks everyone.

Comment: You are not setting the transparent background to your dialog twice. `getWindow()` get the windows of the Fragment or Activity holding your Adapter, not the dialog. (`selectCategory.getWindow()` != `getWindow()`). But Idk exactly what is the impact of changing the background of it

Comment: Ok, I understood the value of View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView(); - what view it gets. I was trying to set a transparent background for my activity not the dialog. It seems kinda that setting the activity background as transparent causes the activity to kinda start again or something like that, because I noticed that opening and closing the dialog multiple times the elevation shadow under the task bar gets darker and darker, it's visible int he gif as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code when you dismiss or close the dialog,

```
edittext.setSelection(editText.getText().toString().trim().length);
```